# Adding and removing element on an Array from different button clicks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement, state

On html I have three buttons Each button is responsible for specific index of an Array.
When pressed for the first time it should insert element in the index provided and if pressed again it should remove the element. Button should toggle and Array should preserve the previous element with out removing the element:

For example:
On

> pressing all three button for the first time

then Array should look like this `arr= [1,2,3]`

On

> pressing button 2 again

Array should be `arr=[1,,3]`
HTML:

```
<button onClick="test(1,0)">button 1</button>
<button onClick='test(2,1)'>button 2 </button>
<button onClick='test(3,2)'>button 3 </button>
```

JS:

```
const arr=[]

let state
const test = (name,index)=>{
  state= !state
  if(state){
     arr[index]=name
  }else{
    arr.splice(index,1)
  }
  
  console.log(arr)
 
}
```

Comment: [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) removes the element from the array so will not preserve your position. Instead, I think you want to replace `array[index]` with `null` instead. Does this solve your problem? Please include exact errors/the problem you're actually having with your code.

Comment: Your use of `splice` deletes the index and shortens the array, also you can't set an index to be empty explicitly so if that is what you want you would need to create a new array that mirrors the previous one but doesn't assign the relevant index. This seems a fragile pattern though.

Comment: Your call of the `onClick` function is wrong too. You need to use `{}` when doing function calls as currently you're just interpreting a string. E.g you need to do `onClick={() => test(1,0)}`

Comment: @Ranjan Raj Shrestha what do you expect to happen if the 3rd button was clicked first? Would you expect `[null, null, 3]` or `[3]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `arr.splice(index, 1, undefined);` you cannot have 'nothing' between two values in an array it has to be something and to represent 'nothing' you have the 'choice' between null and undefined(depending on your use case, you should choose one over the other) . You could also initialise your array with undefined values.

Comment: You *can* have nothing in an array, but you can't assign nothing to an index.

Answer (score 0):

[**Edit**]: the orginal idea, now using `reactjs`, and using a data-attribute for the 'name' and a css class to set and determine the button state.

```js
class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.getLogBox = () => document.querySelector("#Log");
  }
    
  log(...txt) { 
      this.getLogBox().textContent += `${txt.join("\n")}\n`;
  }
  
  logClear() { 
      this.getLogBox().textContent = ``;
  }
  
  setState() {
    this.state = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-button-name]")]
      .map( btn => btn.classList.contains("on")  ? 
        +btn.dataset.buttonName : 
        undefined );
  }
  
  handleClick(evt) {
    const origin = evt.target;
    
    if (origin.dataset.clear) {
      return this.logClear();
    }
    
    if (!origin.dataset.showstate) {
      origin.classList.toggle("on");
      this.setState();
    } else {
      this.log(`Current state [${this.state}]`);
    }
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <button data-button-name="1" onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
      <button data-button-name="2" onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
      <button data-button-name="3" onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
      <button data-showstate onClick={this.handleClick}>Show state</button>
      <button data-clear onClick={this.handleClick}>Clear log</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  [<Buttons />, ( <pre id="Log"></pre> )],
  document.body
);
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

button[data-button-name]:before {
  content: 'Off';
}

button[data-button-name].on:before {
  content: 'On';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[**Original answer**] It is generally not a good idea to use [inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events). Here's a snippet using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to add a handler for the three buttons. It's using [`data-attrributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to record the 'push state'.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);
const nButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-push-state]").length;
let pushedStates = [...Array(nButtons)];

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.index) {
    console.clear();
    const isPushed = !!(+evt.target.dataset.pushState);
    evt.target.dataset.pushState = +(!isPushed);
    pushedStates = [...document.querySelectorAll("[data-push-state]")]
      .map(btn => !!(+btn.dataset.pushState) ? +btn.dataset.index : undefined);
    console.log(`pushedStates now: [${pushedStates}]`);
  }
}
```

```html
<button data-index="1" data-push-state="0">button 1</button>
<button data-index="2" data-push-state="0">button 2</button>
<button data-index="3" data-push-state="0">button 3</button>
```

Comment: It's a React question, so the [`onClick`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) is not a vanilla inline handler, but the JSX event syntax.

Comment: I see. I'm not that well versed in react. OP may adapt the `handle` method I suppose